# BBox problem with rasterio - Converting KML file to GeoTiff file on Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, kml, rasterio

At my work, I need to convert different kinds of files into Geotiff files. Now I have to convert a banch o KML files. Those came with the coordinates from the corners of the polygon. Using rasterio to convert to GeoTiff, I need to use West, East, South and North coordinates, which is giving me a couple of meters of error from the rigth location. Any advice? My code and the image on Google Earth:

How the coordinates come on KML file:

```
[['POLYGON ((-68.02573239434068 10.458541609679036'], [' -67.97139569083748 10.447019877002532'], [' -67.9631296429911 10.495261426980813'], [' -68.01557210143345 10.506382845074937'], [' -68.02573239434068 10.458541609679036))']
```

Code:

```
  south = np.float64(lat_min)
  north = np.float64(lat_max)
  east = np.float64(lon_min)
  west = np.float64(lon_max)

  with rio.open(png, 'r') as img:
  img = img.read([1])
  img = img.astype('uint16')
  bounds = rio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, 
  img.shape[1], 
  img.shape[2])
  crs = '+proj=latlong'
  show(img) #shows true color
  with rio.open('{}.tiff'.format(file),'w', 
                 driver='GTiff',
                 count=1,
                 height=img.shape[1],
                 width=img.shape[2],
                 dtype=img.dtype,
                 crs=crs,
                 transform= bounds,
                 ) as dst:
        dst.write(img)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`rio.transform.from_bounds` takes in order `width`, `height`.
You are specifiying in order shape[1] then shape[2]

But in the other hand, in `open` you are specifying: `height=img.shape[1], width=img.shape[2]`

I think there lies the issue of your code, you should have written:

```py
 tf = rio.transform.from_bounds(
   west, 
   south, 
   east, 
   north, 
   width=img.shape[2], 
   height=img.shape[1]
)
```

---

I also think you should use `EPSG:4326` as KML crs, as specified in GDAL: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/kml.html

Comment: Thanks, it did help on the message that returned, but it dind't fixed the location error.

Comment: This should have modified the location, no ? (not upper left corner, but the resolutions x,y should change, so the displayed length of your raster)

Comment: You also should set crs="epsg:4326" I think, which is the default for KMLs

Comment: epsg:4326 isn't the CRS of KML, see the standard ~ https://docs.ogc.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html Appendix B KML Coordinate Reference System Definition (Normative).  The CRS is lon/lat ~ http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/LonLat84 NOT the lat/long of EPSG:4326

Comment: Yes OK, but GDAL uses 4326: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/kml.html
This code is based on rasterio which is wrapping GDAL, so I think I would stick to 4326...

Comment: I tryed espg 4326 before, but I'm not sure that all my images will be, so this solution is better.

Comment: Oh your images don't have the same CRS than your KML ? This is it, you need a reprojection then!